# Why is my binary tree not filling up properly?

Tags: c, tree, binary-tree, nodes

I am looking for a way to fill character strings into my binary tree in order of appearance and accessing them in the order I was inputing them into my tree. I just can't figure out a way to create such a tree.

I am given a root node which splits into two branches, the branches themselves also create two more branches. And so on. 
All I want is to create a tree which saves my inputs in the order I am inputting them if that makes sense.

I want the tree to look like this:

```
    A
   / \
  B   C
 / \ / \
 D E F G
```

A,B,C,D,E,F,G and so on are random filenames I need to store in the tree.
How can I store random char strings in an binary tree in the order they appeared? What is the best way to do such a thing? Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code written in C but it doesn't seem to work. The right hand-side is messed up and is stored after the first B leaf. Using the commented printf function you can see that it produces as segmentation fault.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct node
{
  char *titel;
  struct node *A;
  struct node *B;
};

int bitPos (int n)
{
  return n & -n;
}

void display(struct node *leaf)
{
if (leaf != NULL)
{
    display(leaf->A);
    printf("%s\n",leaf->titel);
    display(leaf->B);
}
}

void insert(char* titel, struct node **leaf, int nodeCount, int bitPos)
{
if (*leaf == 0)
{
  *leaf = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  (*leaf)->titel = malloc(strlen(titel)+1);
  strcpy((*leaf)->titel,titel);
  (*leaf)->A = NULL;
  (*leaf)->B = NULL;
}
else
{
 int currentBit = (nodeCount >> bitPos) & 1;
 if (currentBit == 0) {
   // insert to left
   insert(titel, &((*leaf)->A), nodeCount, bitPos - 1);
 }
 else
 {
   // insert to right
   insert(titel, &((*leaf)->B), nodeCount, bitPos - 1);
 }
}
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  struct node *root = 0;
  insert("root",&root,1,bitPos(1));
  insert("chapter_1A",&root,2,bitPos(2));
  insert("chapter_1B",&root,3,bitPos(3));
  insert("chapter_2A",&root,4,bitPos(4));
  insert("chapter_2B",&root,5,bitPos(5));
  insert("chapter_3A",&root,6,bitPos(6));
  insert("chapter_3B",&root,7,bitPos(7));
  insert("chapter_4A",&root,8,bitPos(8));
  insert("chapter_4B",&root,9,bitPos(9));
  display(root);
  //printf("%s\n",root->B->A->titel);
  return 0;
}
```

Input:
    Input as seen in the main function.

```
root => chapter_1A => chapter_1B => chapter_2A => chapter_2B and so on.
```

Should be Output (without the chapter_):

```
        root
       /    \
     1A     1B
    /  \    / \
   2A  2B  3A 3B
  /  \
 4A  4B
```

Actual output from the program using the display function:

```
chapter_4B
chapter_4A
chapter_2B
chapter_2A
chapter_1A
root
chapter_1B
chapter_3A
chapter_3B
```

Comment: see this http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/level-order-tree-traversal/

Comment: And even so the nodes appear to be getting inserted  backwards (that is, the right child is populated before the left). At least going by the fact that ch 4 is before ch 3 in the display.

Comment: What are you expecting as the output of `bitPos()` for the cases where you call it in `main()`?

Comment: the data structure should fit the problem set.   Since want to be able to retrieve the data in the same order as it was inserted, (which has nothing to do with a binary tree) strongly suggest using an array of pointers and each pointer points to a string.  If each entry is generated using `realloc()` and `strdup()` then the whole process becomes very simple

Answer (score 0):

Using a binary tree for this particular purpose makes absolutely no sense. However, I know of several cases where in-order and storage-order [indexing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1675498/references-to-these-functions-relating-to-binary-trees-and-binary-digit-counting) is useful, and that actually leads to the solution in this particular case. Which is:

**If you have a binary tree with N first levels (and thus 2<sup>N</sup>-1 nodes) and K leftmost nodes in the N+1'th level populated, then the path to the next free node is given by K, read from most significant set bit to the least significant bit, zero indicating left child, and one right child.**

You probably won't believe that, but it's true; the key point is that K varies from 0 to 2<sup>N</sup>-1. Let me help you verify the above claim, and solve the stated problem, too.

First, let's define a couple of helper functions.

Let `BITS(n)` return the number of bits in `n`, the unsigned integer (exact) version of `ceil(log(n)/log(2))`. A simple C implementation is

```
size_t BITS(size_t value)
{
    size_t  result = 0;
    while (value) {
        result++;
        value >>= 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Let `REV(v, n)` return the bit-reversed value of `n`-bit quantity `v`. For example, `REV(1, 1) = 1`, `REV(1, 2) = 2`, `REV(1, 4) = 8`, `REV(7, 3) = 7`, and so on. (Here, "bit-reversed" means 010011<sub>B</sub> to 110010<sub>B</sub> in binary, thus `REV(19,6) = 50`.) A simple generic implementation in C is

```
size_t REV(size_t value, size_t bits)
{
    size_t  result = 0;
    while (bits-->0) {
        result = (result << 1) | (value & 1);
        value >>= 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Let `FBT(n)` produce the [OEIS A092323](http://oeis.org/A092323) integer sequence; i.e. `FBT(0) = 0`, `FBT(1) = 1`, `FBT(2) = 1`, `FBT(3) = 3`, `FBT(4) = 3`, `FBT(5) = 3`, `FBT(6) = 3`, `FBT(7) = 7`, and so on. The name is an acronym for "full binary tree", indicating the size of the largest full binary tree with at most `n` nodes. For an unsigned 32-bit `n`, `FBT(n)` can be implemented in C as

```
uint32_t set_low_bits(uint32_t u)
{
    u |= u >> 1;
    u |= u >> 2;
    u |= u >> 4;
    u |= u >> 8;
    u |= u >> 16;
    /* Add u |= u >> 32; for 64-bit u */
    return u;
}

uint32_t FBT(uint32_t n)
{
    return set_low_bits((n + 1) >> 1);
}
```

If the tree is empty, the new node to be added becomes the root node, of course. Otherwise, let's assume you have `count` nodes populated. Compute

```
full = FBT(count);
levels = BITS(full);
path = REV(count - full, levels);
```

Here, `full` is the number of nodes in initial full levels in the tree. `levels` is the number of levels in the tree when the new node is added; i.e., one plus the number of full levels in the tree before the new node is added. Before the new node is added, there are `count - full` leftmost nodes populated in the final level. `path` is then the path from `root` to the new node to be added, read from least significant bit up, with zero indicating left child, and 1 right child.

So, let's say you have a non-empty tree with root at `root`, a new node as `newnode`, a temporary node pointer `parent`, and the aforementioned three unsigned integer variables. To add `newnode` to the non-empty tree, you do

```
    parent = root;
    while (levels-->1) {
        if (path & 1)
            parent = parent->right;
        else
            parent = parent->left;
        path >>= 1; /* Equivalent to path = path / 2; */
    }

    if (path & 1)
        parent->right = newnode;
    else
        parent->left = newnode;
```

Note that I have verified the logic works with a test program, but to ensure I'm not giving anyone their homework, and instead help them learn, I copy-pasted the interesting nuggets here. Therefore, there might be copy-paste errors. If you find any, or suspect you found one, let me know in a comment and I'll verify and fix.

---

To test tree and graph algorithms and programs implementing such, I recommend outputting the data in Graphviz [DOT language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_(graph_description_language)); a simple text language you can use to draw graphs or trees by specifying the node relationships. Redirect the output to a file, and supply the file to `dot`, and you get a nice graphical representation of your tree.

Here is a simple example that saves the .dot file to a named file instead, for ease of use in all operating systems:

```
struct node {
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
    char        *value;
};

static void dot_node_recurse(FILE *out, struct node *at)
{
    fprintf(out, "\t\"%p\" [ label=\"%s\" ];\n", (void *)at, at->value);
    if (at->left) {
        dot_node_recurse(out, at->left);
        fprintf(out, "\t\"%p\" -> \"%p\";\n", (void *)at, (void *)(at->left));
    }
    if (at->right) {
        dot_node_recurse(out, at->right);
        fprintf(out, "\t\"%p\" -> \"%p\";\n", (void *)at, (void *)(at->right));
    }
}

int dot_node(const char *filename, struct node *root)
{
    FILE *out;

    if (!filename || !filename[0])
        return -2; /* NULL or empty filename */
    if (!root)
        return -3; /* No tree to save */

    out = fopen(filename, "w");
    if (!out)
        return -1; /* Cannot open file (for writing) */

    fprintf(out, "digraph {\n");
    dot_node_recurse(out, root);
    fprintf(out, "}\n");

    if (ferror(out)) {
        fclose(out);
        return -4; /* Write error */
    }
    if (fclose(out))
        return -4; /* Write error */

    return 0;
}
```